# Ожидание завершения выполнения запроса?

Tags: java, android

Господа!
Пишу сервер приложение на android, которое обрабатывает get запрос.
Обработчику нужно время чтобы подготовить ответ, например взять изображение с камеры, обработать и
отправить клиенту.  Для этого я запускаю поток:

```
if(ClientRequest.indexOf("Look")!=-1) {
                  myCamera.takeImage();
                  Thread waitImageReady = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                      @Override
                      public void run() {
                          Integer counter = 0;
                          while (!myCamera.imageReady){
                              try {
                                  Thread.sleep(100);
                                  counter++;
                              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                  e.printStackTrace();
                              }
                          }
                          answerServer.TypeContent = ImageContent;
                          answerServer.AnswerImage = getBytesImage(MyData.INSTANCE.getCurrentImageName(),false);
                          showMessage(String.format("Counter =%d",counter),Color.RED);
                      }
                  });
                  waitImageReady.start();
                  return answerServer;
              }
```

Но, я не очень давно в теме и мне кажется в java-android есть лучшая реализация этого процесса?

Comment: посмотрите в сторону rxJava или WorkManager

Comment: `ExecutorService executor3 = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        executor3.submit(() -> {
//here your code
        });`, но Thread тоже пойдёт.